# How to get a key from custom keyboard, to fill 2 rows

Tags: android

I have made a custom keyboard on android for some numeric inputs,
in this keyboard I have an "OK" button and I want that button to fill 2 rows.

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="50%p" android:horizontalGap="1px"
    android:verticalGap="1px" android:keyHeight="40dip">
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_delete_512" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="C" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyLabel="OK" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="00"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="#" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

[image]

My objective is to have the bottom row to contain 3 columns, and the "OK" button, to fill 2 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
    <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" />
    <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyLabel="OK" android:keyHeight="80dip" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="00"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
    <Key android:codes="0" android:keyLabel="0" />
    <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyLabel="#" android:horizontalGap="25%p" />
</Row>
```

Comment: works nicely thanks :) , any chance you can explain why the 80dip (perhaps de default is 40? )

Comment: @Ric yes, you are right, that's just a double value of the default `keyHeight`